# Using functions inside of functions

Tags: python, function

I'm new to python and am learning about functions, however using functions inside of functions is confusing me. The example is

```
def print_lyrics():
    print( "I am a lumberjackm and I'm ok." )
    print( "I sleep all night and I work all day." )

def repeat_lyrics():
    print_lyrics()
    print_lyrics()

print(repeat_lyrics)
```

The output to this is `<function repeat_lyrics at 0x000002F5569D5E50>` and I have no idea what that means. I just want to be able to print `repeat_lyrics` function and have it use the `print_lyrics` function. Could someone please help me out? :)

Comment: you forgot `()` after `repeat_lyrics` in line `print( repeat_lyrics() )`

Comment: you have to use `()` to execute function - if you don't use `()` then you doesn't execute it but you can assign it to other variable - ie. `show = print` and later you can use `show("Hello World!")` and it will execute `print()`

Comment: `print(repeat_lyrics)` gives you information about value in variable `repeat_lyrics` - it shows that you have function in this variable, its name is `repeat_lyrics` and it is in memory at address `0x000002F5569D5E50`

Comment: Hint: inside the `repeat_lyrics` function, where you wrote `print_lyrics()`, why did you (correctly) *not* only write `print_lyrics`?

Comment: Oh I added the parentheses to 'print_lyrics' in the 'repeat_lyrics' function because it wasn't printing the phrases without them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a function is an object like everything else.

So, you can assign a function to a variable, print it, etc. To call a function (even from a variable it's been assigned to), you pass it a set of parameters in parentheses, that's the syntax for calling a function.

So:

```
def hello():
    print('hello')


# print a representation of the function object
print(hello)
# assign the function to a variable
bonjour = hello
# call the function (printing "hello")
hello()
# calling the function assigned to the variable (also printing "hello")
bonjour()
```

In fact, after `bonjour = hello`, there is no difference between `bonjour` and `hello`, they are both just names, pointing at the exact same function initially defined as `hello`.

So, where you wrote:

```
print(repeat_lyrics)
```

That's not wrong, as it prints the function, but you probably wanted to execute it:

```
repeat_lyrics()
```

Also note that a function that doesn't explicitly return something, will return `None`. So:

```
print(repeat_lyrics())
```

Would execute the function and then print what it returns, so it also prints `None`.

Answer (score -2):

You can just call the repeat_lyrics function and you do not need to use print

Comment: This doesn't add anything to what was already said in the comments and isn't really an answer, just another comment.